# Создать класс углов на плоскости

Tags: c++, ооп

Помогите решить, пожалуйста.

Создать класс углов на плоскости с данными-членами значение угла в градусах и минутах. Перегрузить операторы ввода и вывода объекта, сложения и вычитания углов. Создать функции-члены для перевода угла из градусов в радианы и наоборот, вычисления тригонометрических функций. Создать пример для демонстрации возможностей класса.

UPD:
Вот что у меня есть: http://pastie.org/9328088

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Angle
{
    static const double Pi;
    public: Angle(double deg = 0.0, double amin = 0.0): _angle(deg + amin / 60.0) {}

    double getAngle() const
    {
        return _angle;
    }

    double transInRad() const
    {
        return _angle * Pi / 180;
    }

    double transInDeg() const
    {
        return transInRad() * 180 / Pi;
    }

    double sin() const
    {
        return std::sin(transInRad());
    }

    double cos() const
    {
        return std::cos(transInRad());
    }

    double tan() const
    {
        return std::tan(transInRad());
    }

    private: double _angle;
};

const double Angle::Pi = 3.14159265358979323;

int main()
{
    Angle a1(25.0, 18.0);

    std::cout << "Угол:\n" << a1.getAngle() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Переводим его в радианы:\n" << a1.transInRad() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Затем обратно в градусы:\n" << a1.transInDeg() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Вычисляем sin угла:\n" << a1.sin() << "\ncos:\n" << a1.cos() << "\ntg:\n" << a1.tan() << "\nctg:\n" << 1/a1.tan();

    return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно ещё "Перегрузить операторы ввода и вывода объекта, сложения и вычитания углов."

Comment: @unitek, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @BogolyubskiyAlexey и @Flammable, добавил. Посмотрите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

[Можете прочитать вот тут, вроде доступно и подробно написано.](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132014/).

Вот еще пара строк для Вашего класса:

```
class Angle
{
    ...
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Angle& dt);
    friend const Angle operator+(const Angle& left, const Angle& right);
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Angle& dt)
{
    os << "deg = " << dt.deg << ", dt.amin = " << amin;
    return os;
}

const Angle operator+(const Angle& left, const Angle& right)
{
    return Angle(left.deg + right.deg, left.amin + right.amin);
}

// main()
std::cout << "Angle: " << a1 << "\n"; // будет типа Angle: deg = 25, amin = 18
```

Comment: @Gimka: Не-а. Вы [не можете](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/output-operator.html) определить `ostream& operator<<` при помощи member function (откуда взялись `deg` и `amin`?).

Comment: Да, Вы правы, с аргументом накосячил и не вписал, да и вообще тип левый от копипаста остался :) Еще и не видно, что они дружественные. Поправил.

Comment: @Gimka: О, другое дело, +1.